# How to delete a published crate from crates.io?

Tags: rust

I have accidentally published my private crate to crates.io. How do I delete it? I checked the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/publishing.html) but it seems like there is no way to delete a published crate.

Comment: I dont think you can delete crates once published,

Comment: Prevention is possible: [`publish = false`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-publish--field-optional)

Answer (score 25):

#### Prevention

To avoid this situation in the future, ensure that you include:

```
[package]
# ...
publish = false
```

in your crate's Cargo.toml. See [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-publish--field-optional).

#### Mitigation

Immediately [yank](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/publishing.html#cargo-yank) the crate using:

```
cargo yank --vers <your-version>
```

This will prevent any other crate to accidentally start depending on it.

If any secret was accidentally published (passwords, keys, ...), consider them no longer secret and take appropriate steps to replace them with fresh ones.

#### Removal

Contact help at crates.io and explain the situation, asking for removal.

If your explanation is well-founded, and the crate has not been downloaded and thus depended on, they have no reason to refuse helping.

Please be patient; once the crate is yanked nobody can start depending on it anyway, so there should be little time pressure. Give the team a few days to actually perform the removal.

If the matter is time sensitive for some reason, you can hop on IRC or Discourse and grab the attention of someone with the powers to perform the removal. Ask and you'll be directed to such a person.

Comment: In my case, it was just silly rust- prefix I did not want in my crate name. I republished under the correct name, and the help contact crates.io responded to my delete request saying they do not delete crates "except for legal reasons or when the crates violate our policies, to keep the registry as immutable as possible" which sounds very reasonable IMO. There is a lot of stuff going behind the scene of a big repository like that, so, I definitely respect their policy.

Answer (score 6):

The [Crates.io policies](https://crates.io/policies) say this under *Removal*:

> We will do what the law requires us to do, and address flagrant violations of the Rust Code of Conduct. […] Crates.io will respect Mozilla Legal’s decisions with regards to content that is hosted.

I suggest to send mail to `help@crates.io` as a start, and if they prove uncooperative, escalate to Mozilla Legal.  Only as a last resort, add a deliberate Code of Conduct violation to trigger the removal.

**EDIT** I agree that this is not a desirable situation, so I submitted a [pull request with a proposed policy change](https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io/pull/1506).

Comment: As a moderator, the idea of recommending violating the Code of Conduct does not sit well with me.

Comment: @MatthieuM. This code of conduct is only a private set of rules of a private company. There is nothing illegal in this recommendation.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I said *as a last resort* (after the typo fix), for this very reason. Unfortunately, Crates.io does not document any other removal procedure.

Comment: Because there is no other removal procedure. This is by design: [to avoid breaking other packages](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/). Instead `cargo` allow you to [yank a crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/publishing.html#cargo-yank).

Comment: @mcarton No, yank is not here for that, as doc said "This feature is not intended for deleting accidentally uploaded secrets, for example."

Comment: @FlorianWeimer: Just because there is no officially documented procedure does not mean that the administrators are not reasonable human beings; this is the Rust community we are talking about here. I find immediately recommending nuclear options as fallbacks (legal and CoC violations) to be quite unnecessary.

Comment: @Boiethios: Just because it's not illegal does not mean it's welcome.

Comment: @MatthieuM. "reasonable" is a personal definition and this discussion isn't about value judgements. Per their own statement: "Our policy is that we don't remove crates for any reason unless we are legally required to. If you were to contact us requesting a crate removal, you would get this reply:" (see the PR above). So it seems that answer is actually the only correct one.

Claiming they have "no reason to refuse helping" is an assumption on your part that contradicts available evidence.

Comment: There _is_ an officially documented procedure and the procedure is they will not help if you ask, only if you demand legally or if their community determines CoC violation.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot delete a crate once it is published. However, you can [yank it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/publishing.html#cargo-yank) to mark your crate as not usable: basically, nobody will use it, and no or few people will want to see the content. This policy allows to forbid the arbitrary breakage of other crates that use your package as a dependency.

If you have code or information in this crate that you do not want to be public, refer to [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52640114/4498831).